# Tell wordpress to show a single page instead of an archive page

Tags: custom-post-types, php, wp-query, archives, custom-post-type-archives

my wordpress site urls like this: https://example.com/?pid=a125a5&lang=en and query of my archive page like this:

```
<?php

$the_slug = get_query_var('pid');

if ($the_slug){

if ( $post = get_page_by_path( $the_slug, OBJECT, 'myposttype' ) )
    $id = $post->ID;
else
    $id = 0;
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="warpper">



    <?php ;
    $args = array(
        'name'        => $the_slug,
        'post_type'   => 'myposttype',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'numberposts' => 1,
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) :   while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();    ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>

<?php endwhile; else: ?><?php endif; ?>
<php } else{...};
```

its work but commands like `is_single()` return false and wordpress not showing edit post in admin bar.

Answer (score 0):

To show single page for your `Custom Post Type` you can use `single-post-type.php` file where you need to add your `post type` name after `single-` and use a query on this file. WordPress will use this file to show a single page of your CPT.

Comment: then how i can change single page url to this? https://example.com/?pid=a125a5&lang=en

Comment: You don't need to change URL, URL remains the same but your CPT will use a `single-post-type.php` template rather than `single.php`. You can still get the `get_query_var('pid');` as above without checking `is_single()`.

Comment: im moving my site from another cms to wordpress for google index links must be same

Comment: Yes please check Settings > Permalinks for URL. Default URL of WordPress posts are similar to the one you have now.

Answer (score 0):

The `is_single()` function will return always `false` in the archive page template. Cause, the page is archive page template.